# How to perform GRASS v.rast.stats via QGIS

Tags: grass-gis, statistics

I have been using qgis for the last few months. I got interested in using GRASS tools through QGIS. I wanted to compute zonal statistics for a raster surface for a given polygon layer. I loaded the raster and the vector successfully into QGIS and GRASS. Then I used v.rast.stats Tool to compute zonal statistics and the program runs without any error. Here is a screenshot of the analysis:

[image]

But I can't see the results in my vector map. When I open the attribute table, no new column has been added. Can anyone advice me on how to get a new column with the computed value?

Thanks

Zaman

Comment: what does `v.info Gindustry@mapset1` yield?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't find any Tool called v.info. Can you please provide a screenshot of how to get this Tool?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the GRASS plugin, you are working in GRASS, not in QGIS and the results will be written to the GRASS layer, not directly to the layer displayed in QGIS.

1) in GRASS GIS:

[image]

Result:

[image]

The solution: reload your layer from GRASS GIS.

If you want directly work in QGIS with the commands of GRASS, you use GRASS in the Toolbox of the menu "Processing", but no v.rast.stats !

Comment: Thanks Gene for your kind reply. I have been able to solve the problem.